# Displaying email in navigation drawer after logging in

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to show email from login.java page in the navigation drawer after they login to Android App. I am getting a FATAL EXCEPTION error and java.lang.NullPointerException when I run.

I have put code into DoctorHome.java:

```
package com.example.medicationmanagementsystem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.example.medicationmanagementsystem.DAO.DatabaseHelper;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class DoctorHome extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    TextView txtDisplayEmail;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.doctor_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        txtDisplayEmail = findViewById(R.id.emaildisplay);
        txtDisplayEmail.setText(myDb.getEmail());

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
    //END

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_createprescription:
                Intent createpresintent = new Intent(DoctorHome.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(createpresintent);
                break;
            case R.id.viewprescriptions:
                Intent presintent = new Intent(DoctorHome.this, ViewListContents.class);
                startActivity(presintent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_addpatients:
                Intent createpatientintent = new Intent(DoctorHome.this, NewPatient.class);
                startActivity(createpatientintent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_viewpatients:
                Intent viewpatientintent = new Intent(DoctorHome.this, ViewPatientListContents.class);
                startActivity(viewpatientintent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Intent logoutintent= new Intent(DoctorHome.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(logoutintent);
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
//getting email
    public String getEmail() throws SQLException {
        String email = "";
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_USERS, new String[] {COL_USER_EMAIL},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                email = cursor.getString(0);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        return email;
    }
```

I am using SQLite as the database to save user details. I just need the email from this to display in the textview emaildisplay in the navigation header. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You forgot to initialize `myDb`: `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);`

Comment: Thank you, however still getting the same error unfortunately!

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.medicationmanagementsystem, PID: 1494
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.medicationmanagementsystem/com.example.medicationmanagementsystem.DoctorHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to initialize `myDb` before using it like this:

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Also `txtDisplayEmail` is not inside your activity's layout, so this:

```
txtDisplayEmail = findViewById(R.id.emaildisplay);
```

returns `null`.
What you should do is find `txtDisplayEmail` inside the `NavigationView`'s header.
Change to this:

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
txtDisplayEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.emaildisplay);
txtDisplayEmail.setText(myDb.getEmail());
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

But the method `getEmail()` of `DatabaseHelper` does not return the user's email (if this is what it is supposed to do).
It just loops over all the emails of the table and returns the last one.
So change it to return the email of the logged in user.

Comment: Thanks very much, txtemaildisplay is now displaying an email but yes you were right it is just using the last emailed registered in the database.

Answer (score 1):

instead of **findViewById(R.id.emaildisplay);**

try **navigationView.findViewById(R.id.emaildisplay);**

I assume emaildisplay is part of nvigationView not the activity layout.